# How to chain selectors in Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

While trying to manipulate the layout of external sites I am often forced to use a chain of selectors to target the specific element I want. The first time I encountered this I was offered a jQuery solution and it is very easy to get results. I would prefer not to rely on jQuery and would like to know how feasible this is in standard Javascript. Here is an example jQuery 'chain' -

```
$('div[id="entry"] > p[class="header"] > span[id="title"] > div[class*="entry"] > p[class="title"] > a[class*="target"]').. etc
```

So say the HTML structure is roughly

```
<div id="entry">
    <p class="primary">
    <p class="header">
        <span class="side">
        <span id="title">
            <div class="secondary entry">
                <p class="return">
                <p class="title">
                    <a class="img">
                    <a class="mytargetelement">
```

So how is this possible normally? Thanks.

Comment: I assume that your hierarchy is more complicated than your example, but you could simplify you selector to `$('div#entry a[class*=element]')`

Comment: Yes, apologies. I guess I was trying to make it look the chain more complicated than it needed to be to see if it was possible in fine detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enter [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).

It's what jQuery uses internally for browsers that support it. The syntax is the same as in jQuery (Sizzle) selectors, see [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. The lack of IE6/7 compatibility isn't an issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't pretty..

For each nested/chained element you can get its children via [childNodes](http://javascript.gakaa.com/node-childnodes-7-0-6-.aspx) property.  And then let the looping commence.   :/   You'd then have to recursively loop through all children and children's children, and so on, until you find the appropriately matched element(s).

***Updated***:

To check for part of class name, you can do something like this:

```
if (element.className.indexOf('myClass') >= 0) {
   // found it!
}
```

Comment: I would say recursion is more appropriate for exploring the DOM tree.

Comment: @Roland, that's exactly what I meant.  I assumed it was implied when I mentioned looping, but perhaps not clear enough.

Comment: @Kon Thanks a lot. I was unaware of the element.className method. That will be useful to remember.

Comment: No prob.  just remember it's a property, not a method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid jQuery and only use complex CSS selectors then the [SizzleJS library](http://sizzlejs.com/) might be what you need. It's a lot easier than doing it yourself every time you're looking for a DOM element!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it was actually Sizzle and not jQuery per se. I just wanted to see if it was possible without using any external library at all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectors(){
      var temp= [];      //array for storing multiple id selectors.
      for(var i = 0;i<arguments.length;i++){
      if(typeof arguments[i] === 'string')
      temp.push(document.getElementById(arguments[i])); 
            }

          return temp; //for chanining
      },

 now call the function as many time as you want like
selectors('p').selectors('anyid')
```

Comment: try this it will work always.now you can modify this function as per your need like you you want Xpath selector then just modify the function.simply NO USE OF JQUERY