# Selecting img child of div child of div with ID with JavaScript but Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to gather a fairly complicated wrapped set using JavaScript whilst avoiding having to load the jQuery library (or any other library, eg. Sizzle).

Within the following HTML I want to form a wrapped set consisting of every `img` element:

```
<div id='slider'>

   <div><img src="../../images/rby/rby (30).jpg" width="720" height="507"></div>
   <div><img src="../../images/rby/rby (18).jpg" width="720" height="507"></div>
   <div><img src="../../images/rby/rby (12).jpg" width="720" height="507"></div>

</div>
```

I've tried using the `querySelectorAll()` method mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562815/how-to-chain-selectors-in-javascript-without-jquery) but I'm unable to generalise the lesson to my own specific needs. Can someone help perhaps?!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the syntax of `querySelectorAll()` is the same as jQuery's selector syntax. So, your solution would be:

```
// If you want only the <img> elements inside <div> elements:
var my_images = document.querySelectorAll('div#slider div img');

// If you want all images inside div#slider:
var my_images = document.querySelectorAll('div#slider img');
```

Of course, if you don't mind the lack of IE6 / IE7 support, you're good to go!

Comment: `div#slider` can be simply `#slider`, since there should only be one `#slider`.

Comment: The syntax of `qSA` is only the same up to the point of jQuery's (Sizzle's) non-standard extensions. jQuery includes a long list of selectors that will result in a DOM Exception in `qSA`.

Comment: True, but for the OP's purpose the syntax is identical.

Comment: The similarity of syntax is good to learn, thank you. However if what you say above is correct then would replacing `document.querySelectorAll` with `jquery` (or $) in front of the brackets have the same effect? Because that's not the case with my code...

Comment: Yeah, just didn't want OP to think he could safely mine the jQuery selector docs for `qSA` selectors.

Comment: It should do, so long as you have wrapped it inside the `document.ready` function?

Comment: Oh my, I'm having trouble with this one... Do you think you could make [this jsFiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/h5a4n/2/) to show me...

Comment: I'm so sorry to keep doing this, but I'm getting nowhere by myself. So I've made the JSfiddle exactly like the page and I'm using the jquery selector and it works but it doesn't when I use your pure-JS method. Can you make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/h5a4n/4/

Comment: Boom! Thank you soo much. I would never have got that.

Answer (score 1):

Like this (note, cross-browser but may not deal with more complex examples as well as `.querySelectorAll` might, depending)?

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider'),
    imgs = slider.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    selected = images = document.querySelectorAll('#slider img');

console.log(imgs);
console.log(selected);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5a4n/1/

(Note, the `#slider img` was stolen shamelessly from am not i am's answer. Not that I couldn't have figured it out on my own... `:P`)